# Why ADL has a different behavior for operator function than other functions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I have created a `C` class inside a `NS_C` namespace that way:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS_C {
  template <typename T>
  class C {
    public:
      C operator+(long) {
        std::cout << "NS_C::C::operator+\n";
        return *this;
      }

      void not_operator(C<T>, long) {
        std::cout << "NS_C::C::not_operator\n";
      }

      void call() {
        *this + 0;
        not_operator(*this, 0);
      }
  };
}
```

The function `call` is supposed to call `NS_C::C::operator+` then `NS_C::C::not_operator`. To test this behavior, I run this small program:

```
int main()
{
  NS_C::C<int> ci;
  ci.call();

  return 0;
}
```

The output is what I expected:

```sh
> g++ -o example example.cpp && ./example
NS_C::C::operator+
NS_C::C::not_operator
```

Now, I want to create a new class `A` within a separate namespace `NS_A` and add to this namespace two generic overloads of `operator+` and `not_operator` functions:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS_A {
  class A {};

  template <typename T>
  T operator+(T t, int)
  {
    std::cout << "NS_A::operator+\n";
    return t;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void not_operator(T, int)
  {
    std::cout << "NS_A::not_operator\n";
  }
}
```

Thanks to ADL, a call to `call` member function from an `NS_C::C<NS_A>` object will call the overloaded `NS_A::operator+` as it is better match (the second parameter is `int` in `NS_A::operator+` and `long` in `NS_C::C::operator+`).
However, I don't understand why the same behavior doesn't occur for my `not_operator` function. Indeed, `NS_C::C::not_operator` will still be called from `call` function.

Let's use the following main function:

```
int main()
{
  NS_C::C<NS_A::A> ca;
  ca.call();

  return 0;
}
```

I have the following output:

```
NS_A::operator+
NS_C::C::not_operator
```

Why `NS_A::not_operator` is not called in that case?

---

Here is the complete code to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS_A {
  class A {};

  template <typename T>
  T operator+(T t, int)
  {
    std::cout << "NS_A::operator+\n";
    return t;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void not_operator(T, int)
  {
    std::cout << "NS_A::not_operator\n";
  }
}

namespace NS_C {
  template <typename T>
  class C {
    public:
      C operator+(long) {
        std::cout << "NS_C::C::operator+\n";
        return *this;
      } 

      void not_operator(C<T>, long) {
        std::cout << "NS_C::C::not_operator\n";
      }

      void call() {
        *this + 0;
        not_operator(*this, 0);
      }
  };
}   

int main()
{
  NS_C::C<int> ci;
  ci.call();

  NS_C::C<NS_A::A> ca;
  ca.call();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator):

We have in overload sets of candidates for overloaded operator:

> 1) member candidates: if T1 is a complete class or a class currently being defined, the set of member candidates is the result of qualified name lookup of T1::operator@. In all other cases, the set of member candidates is empty.
>
> 2) non-member candidates: For the operators where operator overloading permits non-member forms, all declarations found by unqualified name lookup of operator@ in the context of the expression (which may involve ADL), except that member function declarations are ignored and do not prevent the lookup from continuing into the next enclosing scope. If both operands of a binary operator or the only operand of a unary operator has enumeration type, the only functions from the lookup set that become non-member candidates are the ones whose parameter has that enumeration type (or reference to that enumeration type)

Whereas for the other, we only have [unqualified_lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition)

There is even an example in [unqualified_lookup#Overloaded_operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Overloaded_operator)
showing difference between `operator+(a, a)` and `a + a`